# Type Error with sklearn make_scorer Function

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to build a custom scoring function (using sklearn.metrics.make_scorer) to be used in a GridSearhCV object.  The documentation for make_scorer says:

> **score_func** : callable, Score function (or loss function) with
>   signature `score_func(y, y_pred, **kwargs)`.

Here is the code I am using:

```
    class model(object):
        def __init__(self):
            pass

        def fit(self, X, y):
            score_func = make_scorer(self.make_custom_score)

            clf = GradientBoostingClassifier()

            model = GridSearchCV(estimator=clf, 
                                 param_grid=grid, 
                                 scoring=score_func,
                                 cv=3)

            model.fit(X, y)               
            return self


        def make_custom_score(y_true, y_score):
            df_out = pd.DataFrame()

            df = pd.DataFrame({'true': y_true.tolist(), 'probability':
                                y_score.tolist()})

            for threshold in np.arange(0.01, 1.0, 0.01):   

                above_thresh = df[df['probability'] > threshold].groupby('true').count().reset_index()   


                tp = above_thresh.loc[[1.0]]['probability'].sum()


                df_threshold = pd.DataFrame({'threshold': [threshold], 'tp': tp})
                df_out = df_out.append(df_threshold)

            df_out = df_out.sort_values(by = ['threshold'], ascending = False)

            tp_score = tp[5]


            return tp_score
```

The error I get is:

TypeError: make_custom_score() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given.

I am planning on adding more to the scoring function using the **kwargs in the future so I would like to use make_scorer if I can.

Comment: See this question for explanation of self: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44741054/python-class-methods-when-is-self-not-needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe 3 positional arguments are being passed since you called the method on an instance. Try adding self as the first param to that method.

```
def make_custom_score(self, y_true, y_score):
```